# linker command failed with exit code 1 after I upgrade to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, linker-errors

After I upgraded to El Capitan and Xcode 7, I cannot build my app. I keep getting duplicate symbols on all of my global variables. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHmFl.png)

```
//Global.h
#ifndef Global_h
#define Global_h

extern NSInteger pickerConstantOne, pickerConstantTwo,numberOfDays, monthOfToday;

NSInteger pickerConstantOne, pickerConstantTwo,numberOfDays, monthOfToday;

#endif /* Global_h */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misdeclared those variables; remove this statement from the header:

```
NSInteger pickerConstantOne, pickerConstantTwo,numberOfDays, monthOfToday;
```

and move it into a `.m` file.

You should also review exactly why you are using global variables in the first place as you certainly don't need to be.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I use global variables because the variables needed to be visible across multiple view controllers. To me, it seems the most convenient way to do. But I don't get it. Up until Xcode 7, the codes were working fine. I wish to understand why...